# jQuery AJAX fail function - error on page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

My web page loads data into it via AJAX calls, all works fine apart from if you try to navigate away from the page while the AJAX is loading data. If I navigate away from the page it fires the fail function, however there is no data within it so I just get an alert box that says "error".

My code:

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    $('#ajaxloadergif').fadeOut(1000);
    if (textStatus !== 'abort') {
        alert(textStatus+'\n'+errorThrown);     
    }      
});
```

That console.log spits out these values for the object:

> readyState: 0 
>   responseText: "" 
>   status: 0 
>   statusText: "error"

Now to add more complexity, I've seen a few other posts which suggest to check for the readyState or status to be greater than 0. So I decided to do a test, where I loaded the web page, stopped the web server running and ran the AJAX again. Unfortunately it returned the exact same details.

So I basically need some suggestions to get a helpful error message, that doesn't fire when there isn't an error.

Comment: try to save the request inside a var request = $.ajax ...... then set an events that call request.abort() on page change??

Comment: @Vanojx1 I actually already have a function to cancel all the current AJAX requests like you mentioned. I will try it.

Comment: $( window ).unload(function() {}); can be the right event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vanojx1:

```
function CancelAJAX() { // Function to cancel all outstanding AJAX requests
    $(AJAXRequest).each(function() { // Loop through all the requests
        if (!this.Complete) { // If the request is not flagged as completed
            this.Request.abort(); // Abort the request
        }
    });
    AJAXRequest = []; // Reset the AJAXRequest variable
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    CancelAJAX();
}
```

Which is set up with:

```
var RequestIndex = AJAXRequest.length
AJAXRequest[RequestIndex] = {};
AJAXRequest[RequestIndex].Complete = false;
AJAXRequest[RequestIndex].Request = $.post(...
```

This is done in the `.done` callback:

```
AJAXRequest[RequestIndex].Complete = true;
```